# How can I save edited JSON file to web server using JSONEditor?

Tags: javascript, html, json, ajax, asp.net-web-api

I'm using the JSONEditor (https://github.com/josdejong/jsoneditor) to load a json file, make changes and save the file. This works great but it only saves the JSON file to the folder specified according to your browser settings. Here's the demo code (https://github.com/josdejong/jsoneditor/blob/master/examples/04_load_and_save.html):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <title>JSONEditor | Load and save</title>

  <link href="../dist/jsoneditor.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <script src="../dist/jsoneditor.js"></script>

  <script src="https://bgrins.github.io/filereader.js/filereader.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/FileSaver.js/2014-11-29/FileSaver.min.js"></script>

  <style>
    html, body {
      font: 11pt sans-serif;
    }
    #jsoneditor {
      width: 500px;
      height: 500px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Load and save JSON documents</h1>
<p>
  This examples uses HTML5 to load/save local files.
  Powered by <a href="http://bgrins.github.io/filereader.js/">FileReader.js</a> and
  <a href="https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js">FileSaver.js</a>.<br>
  Only supported on modern browsers (Chrome, FireFox, IE10+, Safari 6.1+, Opera 15+).
</p>
<p>
  Load a JSON document: <input type="file" id="loadDocument" value="Load"/>
</p>
<p>
  Save a JSON document: <input type="button" id="saveDocument" value="Save" />
</p>

<div id="jsoneditor"></div>

<script>
  // create the editor
  var editor = new JSONEditor(document.getElementById('jsoneditor'));
  // Load a JSON document
  FileReaderJS.setupInput(document.getElementById('loadDocument'), {
    readAsDefault: 'Text',
    on: {
      load: function (event, file) {
        editor.setText(event.target.result);
      }
    }
  });
  // Save a JSON document
  document.getElementById('saveDocument').onclick = function () {
    // Save Dialog
    fname = window.prompt("Save as...");

    // Check json extension in file name
    if(fname.indexOf(".")==-1){
      fname = fname + ".json";
    }else{
      if(fname.split('.').pop().toLowerCase() == "json"){
        // Nothing to do
      }else{
        fname = fname.split('.')[0] + ".json";
      }
    } 
    var blob = new Blob([editor.getText()], {type: 'application/json;charset=utf-8'});
    saveAs(blob, fname);
  };
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to be able to save the file to the web server. Is there any way for me to save the edited JSON file to the web server? I searched and tried to integrate this library with JSONEditor but no joy:

https://abandon.ie/notebook/simple-file-uploads-using-jquery-ajax

I'm not restricted to ajax so I'll consider anything that works!
Thanks for your advice.
John

UPDATED: Here's the controller code chunk.

```
// POST api/values
    public async void Post()
    {
        string json = await Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        File.WriteAllText(
            HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~\\App_Data\\somefile.json"),
            json
        );
    }
```

I tested this using Postman and it works. What I can't seem to do for the life of me is to now send the edited JSON file to the controller. Here's the modified HTML page where I try unsuccessfully to send the json. For brevity, I'll just add the extra/edited code code:

```
<form id="form1" method="post" enctype="text/plain" action="http://localhost:1651/api/values">
    <input type="file" name="json" id="loadDocument" value="Load"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
```

Edited javascript where I try to return the edited json to the form:

```
document.getElementById('saveDocument').onclick = function () {
    return editor.getText();
  };
```

Please help! How do I send the json to the controller?

Comment: ajax or postback are your two options, essentially. You need to get the data from the editor (`editor.getText()` maybe?) and send that data to the server. Then your server-side script can save it somewhere on the server. Don't think about uploading a "file" because you haven't got one within your page - that's only created during the process of downloading. What you've actually got in your editor is some plain text, so just send that (it's much simpler to achieve anyway). The server can take care of creating a file on its disk and inserting the text into it.

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply. Your suggestion sounds like the best option. I apologize for my ignorance but how exactly could I send the text back to the server and have the server save the text as a JSON file? I'm mainly using C# but not restricted to this.

Comment: An ajax call (made using Javascript within your page) or a traditional form postback are your two options, essentially, for sending the data. If you're familiar with C# then a ASP.NET Web API or MVC controller would probably be the best thing to implement on the server-side for receiving and processing the data. As a rule of thumb, if you're sending the data via ajax, then a Web API controller which just returns a JSON response (and not HTML) is likely the best option. If you want to post the data back and refresh the page with new HTML then use MVC is probably a better fit

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions so far. I created a WEB API controller that takes form data and saves it as JSON. Here's the Controller code:

Comment: you can't "return" data from a click event, the data doesn't go anywhere. Where do you think you're sending it? You need to write that value into a text (or hidden) field (and make sure you do it before the form submits), if you want to send it via a normal postback.